# logo img appears huge on FF & IE, cant insert images into slider/carousel

Tags: css

I have only just started using CSS and I've recently been working on a rather simpel site. I'm nearly done and most of the elements of my site seem to work except but I keep bumping into the same problems.

The first being the site's logo which appears in my header, for some reason it's ridiculously huge with the FF and IE browsers. 
I have tried various containers but I have the feeling that I'm not implementing them in the correct way. I have done this as follows:

```
 <header>    
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span3 no-left-margin">
                        <h1 id="homepage_logo">
                          <a class="brand" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                            <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>assets/img/logo.jpg  
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.item {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
} <--" alt="<?php _e("Mysite") ?>" title="<?php _e("Terugkeren naar de homepagina") ?>" />
```

The second problem I have is with inserting images in to my img slider/carousel.
I tried to implement the urls in various ways (as shown below) but they won't appear on the site.

```
<?php if (is_page('home')): ?>
        <div id="homepage_slider" class="ts_slider">
                <div id="slide1" class="ts_slide white_font">     
                    <img class="slider_bg" src="<?php http://www.mysite.nl/wp-content/uploads/slider_4_bg.jpg ?>/"assets/img/slider_1_bg.jpg />

I hope someone can help me find the problem, thank you guys in advance.
```